# Meaning of "Higher Education Entrance Qualification" in the application form of a german university

Tags: masters, application, germany, europe

I am applying for a masters degree in Mathematics at a University in Germany.

I already have done a bachelors in my home country X ( Bachelor of Arts with math as 1 of subjects)and a masters in my home country X in mathematics.

Consider the screenshot of application in progress(I am asking this question here because no source to contact has been given in the university website):

[Screenshot of application form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIMGU.png)

> Question: What exactly is meant in application form by "University Entrance Qualification"? I have no clue on what should I fill in the form here?

Comment: Even though no contact is given, most unis in Germany do have an "International Office" or similar called institution, that is there to help students from abroad with questions like these. I would check if your uni has one, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To study at a German university, you need a particular kind of qualification called *Hochschulzugangsberechtigung*. And yes, German universities will ask for that even if you have already obtained other university degrees. The form asks for how you have obtained this qualification.

The ordinary way of obtaining the *Hochschulzugangsberechtigung* is the *Abitur*, earned by completing the highest level of school and sitting an exam at the end. As you presumably didn't attend school in Germany, you won't have an *Abitur*. If the country where you did do your secondary education have a concept of "diploma obtained by finishing school which then qualifies you for university", there is a decent chance that this is considered equivalent to an *Abitur* and would thus work.

There are plenty of other ways to obtain the *Hochschulzugangsberechtigung*. The problem is that education is a state-matter in Germany, which means that each *Bundesland* will have their own rules on what exactly you could do. For example, I obtained mine by virtue of having already completed a university degree, as recognized by the state of Northrhine-Westphalia.